# valgrind generated very large xtree

Tags: valgrind, massif

valgrind 3.13 supported xtree http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html

I used it with massif

```
 valgrind --tool=massif --xtree-memory=full --xtree-memory-file=xtmemory.ms.%p
```

Then it generated a 16G file. It is too large to load by massif visualizer.. What is the best practice to use xtree-memory

Comment: Can you simplify the rest that you are running?

Comment: @PaulFloyd It is a very large product, which is hard to simplify... The massif memory profile log the run generated is only 500k.

Answer (score 2):

The massif report contains non detailed snapshots, and some detailed snapshots.
The detailed snapshots only show the allocated memory.
The stack traces that are below the massif threshold will be regrouped
together (i.e. no detail is given for the stack traces below the
thresholds).

The xtree requested with --xtree-memory=full contains 6 different detailed
snapshots, giving the currently allocated bytes/blocks, the total allocated bytes/blocks, the total freed bytes/blocks.
There is no threshold filtering for this xtree report, and so if
your application has a lot of stack traces that are doing a small
proportion of the alloc or free, you will have a lot more data in the
massif xtree report than in the snapshots.

Instead of using a .ms format for the --xtree-memory-file, you might rather
use the .kcg format, and examine it using kcachegrind : the kcachegrind
format is more efficient to store huge amount of stack traces.

See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.xtree
for some more background information.